# Can't open directory in terminal in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I opened an online workspace, after that any folder I open can't appear in terminal I used cd command but it didn't work

I tried using `cd D:\Computer Science` but this error occurred:

> Set-Location : A positional Parameter cannot be foundfound that accept argument 'science'

Comment: Please specify your issue more. What workspace? How did you open it? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Since the directory name has a space character, it is being recognized as two different argument.

Sorround the directory name with qoutes to make it a single argument:

```
cd "D:\Computer Science"
```

Comment: Actually it is a long path `D:\ computer science\cs50\week_2\problem_set_2\bulb_[less]` when i try each folder it works but it isn't working fornthe full path it tells me `can't find path` and every time i exit vs code and reopen it it return to the original directory not the one i choose